# sequences in $\overline{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I want to show if $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are sequences in $[0,\infty]$ with $s_n\to s$ and $t_n\to t$, then:

1.) $s_n+t_n\to s+t$.

And

2.) if $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are increasing, then $s_nt_n\to st$.

Proof of 1: if $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is the usual result. Otherwise suppose at least one of $s,t$ is $\infty$. WLOG, assume $s=\infty$. Then for each $n$, we have $s_n\leq s_n+t_n\leq\infty$, so the squeeze theorem gives $s_n+t_n\to \infty=s+t$.

Proof of 2: we have $s_n\leq s_{n+1}\implies s_nt_n\leq s_{n+1}t_n\leq s_{n+1}t_{n+1}$. Hence $(s_nt_n)$ is also increasing. So by the monotone converge theorem (MCT) of the extended reals, $(s_nt_n)$ converges. Since $s_n\to s$ and $t_n\to t$ (and both sequences are increasing), we have $s_n\leq s$ and $t_n\leq t$ for every $n$. If both sequences are bounded then $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ and this is the usual result. If one is unbounded, WLOG say $(s_n)$, then $s_n\to\infty$ by MCT and so $s_nt_n$ is unbounded. So by the MCT $s_nt_n\to\infty=st$.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my attempts? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to add the case for $t_n\to 0$ and $s_n\to\infty$. Because $t_n$ increases the unique null sequence is $t_n=0,\forall n\in\Bbb N$. Then $s_nt_n=0$ and $s_nt_n\to 0$.

Comment: @Masacroso good point